# Control color of multiple divs using input slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a temperature slider which will change the color of the div(s) based on their melting and boiling points. These values are stored in the following array

```
var elements = {
    hydrogen: {"m_point": "14.01", "b_point": "20.28"},
    helium: {"m_point": "0", "b_point": "4.22"}, 
    //----------so on----------------------------
};
```

and these are the divs whose colors have to be changed

```
<div id="hydrogen"><em>1</em>H<p>Hydrogen</p></div>
<div id="helium"><em>2</em>He<p>Helium</p></div>
<!---------so on----------------------------------->
```

I can't figure out how can I use the value returned by the slider, compare that value with the melting/boiling points given, and change color of div according to that(e.g `blue if value>=m_point, red if value>=b_point` etc.). Basically change color when the state of elements will change from solid->liquid, liquid->gas and vice-versa. I can't use if else statements as I have to specify color each and every time for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide information about your slider I guess it works and you can successfully retrieve the temperature.

It would be easiest if the **relevant** elements (the ones that should change color depending on temperature) had a **common** `class` (here we'll use `class="element"`).

```
var $element = $('.element');
```

We'll assume `var temperature` to be the temperature set by the slider.

I would also change the **temperatures** in your object from **strings** to **numbers**. (`"m_point":14.01,"b_point":20.28`)

Now all we have to do is **iterate** through these **relevant** elements like so:

```
$.each($element, function ( key, value ) {
    var id = value.id;
    if (temperature >= elements[id].b_point) {
        // apply the background-color for gas state
        value.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else if (temperature >= elements[id].m_point) {
        // apply the background-color for liquid state
        value.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        // apply the background-color for solid state
        value.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
});
```

What we have done is "navigate" the object `elements` with [**square bracket notation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) allowing us to use the variable `id`. This also means it only works as long as the `id`-attribute of the `div` matches one of the `properties` of `elements`.

**PS.:**

You'll of course need to **bind** the **script** to some kind of event for it to be executed. I created a [codePen](http://codepen.io/IvanModric/pen/dGQqjN) for you in which it is bound to the `change` event of the input element.